# How to change height of a jpopupmenu in a jcombobox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

[image]

I am working on an application in which I am handling key release event over a editable 'JComboBox', where on every key release a 'JPopupMenu' of the 'JComboBox' appears. I want to increase the height so that user will be able to see more items at a glance without scrolling.
Can anyone please demonstrate how to set the height of 'JPopupMenu' deliberately so that it will show considerable amount of items?
So far i have tried this, but it doesn not work.

```
combo.getComponentPopupMenu().setSize(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following:

```
ComboPopup popup = (ComboPopup) combo.getUI().getAccessibleChild(combo, 0);
((JComponent) popup).setPreferredSize(size);
((JComponent) popup).setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
```

It wold be nice to see your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so I can test whether my proposal works.

Comment: Thanks let me try , i will let you know.

Comment: It became possible to increase the height of JPopupMenu by ur proposal but the scrollbar in the popup remains small so still cant see enough items in popup.

Comment: I have uploaded image please check

Comment: @Deepeshkumar I've added a line. Please try it.

Comment: Oh my god, great, that worked. I appreciate your help.Your knowledge of swing components is adorable. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Deepeshkumar I've already solved same problem. I've got requirement to build a multicolumn combobox. So the posted solution is a part of another one.

Answer (score 4):

A much cleaner approach with using only public API (and without hacks) is to:

- set the width of the JComboBox with its layout (method setLayout on it's parent) - this will also set the width of the JPopupMenu
- set the height of the JPopupMenu with JComboBox.setMaximumRowCount